# `git:remote` is not a heroku command

Tags: git, heroku, git-remote

I deployed an app a few days ago and I am trying to modify some pages. To work on my current version, I wanted to fetch my files from heroku.

I used:

```
heroku git:remote -a fierce-escarpment-8305
```

like it is said on the page 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git.

and received the message:

```
  !    `git:remote` is not a heroku command.
  !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

I don't know what that means. Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right directory - the root of your project?

Answer (score 13):

`heroku git:remote` is a fairly new addition to the Heroku gem ([it was added in version 2.30.0 on 25th July 2012](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/98)).  Since it's so recent, you probably have an older version installed.

Check your version with this command:

```
heroku --version
```

If it's less than 2.30.0 then you can upgrade with this command:

```
gem update heroku
```

You could also remove the Gem completely (it's now deprecated) and switch to the Heroku Toolbelt version of the `heroku` command. You can get it from [toolbelt.heroku.com](https://toolbelt.heroku.com).